# What is the difference between mysql_query() and mysql_result()?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I'm unsure whether I should be using `mysql_result()` or `mysql_query()` when running a query on a database. Does it make a difference in the case below?

```
$usertable = 'tableName';
$colName    = 'columnA'; 
$xlookup = 'columnB';

// Connect to Server
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);

// select db
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// run query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT $colName FROM $usertable where $xlookup = 5");

// pass results to webpage
$a = 51;
$x = array($a, $a, mysql_result($result));
echo json_encode($x);
```

At the moment, whether I use this or not does not make a difference as neither work, but I had  thought an error would stop the code from running.

---

I was trying to use the below code to identify any errors but am not sure if it is correct or not.

```
// This shows the actual query sent to MySQL, and the error. Useful for debugging.
if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die("<html><script language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to run query'), $message</script></html>");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that check is ok. And you often see a shorter notation too. Something like `$result = mysql_query('....') or die('....'.mysql_error());`

Comment: So if $result is just one value (say `10`), can I just return that? Or do I need to do something to the $result? Sorry, I'm still not seeing the difference.

Comment: Even if the query return only one value, it will still return that in a resource object, and you'll still need mysql_result or another function to get that value. Just as you'll need a separate function to connect to the database. There's not one big mysql_query_single_value function that allows you to do those things in one step. Though you can write it yourself (or google it. Someone probably wrote it already).

Comment: From PHP.net (great resource, btw): http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php "Retrieves the contents of one cell from a MySQL result set." There it is. A MySQL result set. Then, further you read: "'result' The result resource that is being evaluated. This result comes from a call to mysql_query()." There you go, you'll need both. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysql_query does the query and returns a resultset.

mysql_result returns the rows from that resultset for you to play with.

Look up some examples [here](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.mysql-result.php).

mysql_result has the distinction of being able to return specific fields, but as other poster noted is slower than the other fetch functions.

Answer (score 2):

mysql_query and mysql_result are two completely different functions which do completely different things.

mysql_query sends an SQL query to the data base.

mysql_result gets a value from a query result according to its row (and optionally a column number, default to zero) number.

That said you should use mysql_fetch_row if you are going to be using more than one datum for each row.

Answer (score 2):

They are different functions. mysql_query executes a query (string) and returns a resource object that you can use to retrieve information from. mysql_result is one of the helper functions that allow you to get that data from the resource. So you'll need both.

Or actually you don't. Once you've used mysql_query, you can use other functions, like mysql_fetch_row too for retrieving data. Most of these functions perform better and more efficient than mysql_result.

Comment: " Most of these functions perform better and more efficient than mysql_result." Can you back that claim up? I've read it several times but never seen any benchmarks or actual reasons.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch From PHP.NET "When working on large result sets, you should consider using one of the functions that fetch an entire row (specified below). As these functions return the contents of multiple cells in one function call, they're MUCH quicker than mysql_result(). Also, note that specifying a numeric offset for the field argument is much quicker than specifying a fieldname or tablename.fieldname argument."

Comment: Thanks, so it might be true that when only needing 1 column from 1 row `$val = mysql_result($resource, 0, 0);` would be marginally faster than $row = `mysql_fetch_row($resource); $val = $row[0];`. What do you think?

Comment: It might be, but I must admit, I've never benchmarked it. Of course, if you need only 1 column and 1 row, it is wise to write your query so that it only returns that single value. If you do that right, the difference between the various functions to read that single value from the resultset may be hardly measurable.